# Disable SSL for Certain Pages Which Contain Insecure Content Coming from External Websites

Tags: php, ssl, iframe

I would like to disable SSL for certain pages  which contain external content (iframes) coming from non-secure external sources. I need to disable SSL only on the pages which have insecure (iframes) content from the external websites don't use https.

This is my server environment,

Centos 6,
PHP,
Apache,
Mysql,

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by putting  two lines of code into the header. The solution is a bit case specific but can inspire those who have similar issues. In my case I already know what the insecure content is (iframe from non-ssl external sites). And pages contain iframes are already satated in the DB. The following code helped me by disabling **https**  where the page has iframe content.

redirection occurs if filetype='code' in the db.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') {
    if ($row2['filetype'] == 'code') {
        header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        exit;
    }
```